# How to get rid of unknown constants for this partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the following PDE problem and required to solve for $u$ using Laplace transforms:

> $$\begin{cases}
> u_{tt}=u_{xx}&x>0,t>0\\
> u(x,0)=0=u_t(x,0)&x>0\\
> u_x(0,t)-hu(0,t)=g(t)&t>0
> \end{cases}$$
>
> where $h>0$ is a constant, $g(t)$ is any continuous function with a Laplace transform. Also assume $u\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ for all $t>0$.

Let $U(x,s)$ be the Laplace transform of $u(x,t)$ with respect to $t$ and we have that $$U=c_1e^{sx} + c_2e^{-sx}$$ I am guessing that since this PDE comes from the modelling of a wave, then $U$ must be bounded and thus $c_1 = 0$. However, to find the value of $c_2$, we need the value of $U(0,s)$. I am having trouble finding $U(0,s)$ since it is in the middle of this equation $$U_x(0,s) - hU(0,s) = G(s)$$ where $G(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $g(t)$. While this reads like a first order differential equation, I don't think it is since $U_x(0,s) \ne \frac{d}{dx}U(0,s)$ but $\frac{d}{dx}U(x,s)$ evaluated at 0. Any hints on how to find $U(0,s)$ would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $U(x,s)=c_1(s)e^{-sx}$. Therefore,
$$
         U_x(x,s)|_{x=0} = -s c_1(s)e^{-sx}|_{x=0}=-sc_1(s).
$$
That gives you
$$
            -(s+h)c_1(s)=G(s) \\
                c_1(s)=-\frac{1}{s+h}G(s)\\
              U(x,s)=-\frac{e^{-sx}}{s+h}G(s)
$$